node-oidc-provider: logout action does not remove session cookies
I am trying to set up logging out of an sso session using node-oidc-provider panva npm.  The process flow seems to be working but there are two cookies that seem to still be present, "_session" and ".session.legacy".  I am not sure what settings I am missing.  The process flow get redirected back to the react ui so the overall flow seems to be working as expected outside of the two cookies not clearing.
features: {
    rpInitiatedLogout: { enabled: true },
    devInteractions: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    introspection: {
        enabled: true
    },
    revocation: { enabled: true },
    encryption: { enabled: true },
    jwtUserinfo: { enabled: true },
    userinfo: { enabled: true },
    pushedAuthorizationRequests: { enabled: true },
    resourceIndicators: {
        defaultResource: (ctx, client, oneOf) => {
            if (oneOf) return oneOf;
            return 'http://example.com';
        },
        enabled: true,
        getResourceServerInfo: (ctx, resourceIndicator, client) => {
            return ({
                accessTokenTTL: 2 * 60 * 60, // 2 hours
                accessTokenFormat: 'jwt',
                jwt: {
                    sign: { alg: 'ES256' },
                }
            });
        },
        useGrantedResource: (ctx, model) => {
            return true;
        }
    }
}


app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    const { redirect_uri } = req.query;
    const id_token = req.cookies.id_token;
    const tokenExpiration = req.cookies.token_expiration;
    const access_token = req.cookies.access_token;
    const expires_in = req.cookies.expires_in;

    res.clearCookie('id_token', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('access_token', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('token_expiration', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('expires_in', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('redirect_uri', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('code_verifier', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('state', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    const endSessionUrl = `${process.env.URL_AUTHORITY}/oidc/session/end?id_token_hint=${id_token}&post_logout_redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)}`;

    res.redirect(endSessionUrl);
});


Would this also clear the oidc-provider session from a db perspective?

Are you sure the session has a valid Refresh token?
Your session object maybe remaining with an invalidated refresh token so that your user info persists for marketing.
jwtUserinfo: { enabled: true },

if your refresh token doesn't work, it doesn't matter.

I don't think I want a refresh token for this situation.  I want the session to also end after a certain time limit.


Clear _session and .session.legacy Cookies: Add res.clearCookie
statements for both _session and .session.legacy cookies.

Ensure Correct Path and Domain: Verify that the path and domain of
the cookies match those used when the cookies were set.

the session cookies _session and .session.legacy are cleared upon
logout, you need to explicitly clear these cookies as well. These
cookies are usually set by node-oidc-provider to maintain session
state
//
    app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
        const { redirect_uri } = req.query;
        const id_token = req.cookies.id_token;

    // Clear your custom cookies
    res.clearCookie('id_token', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('access_token', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('token_expiration', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('expires_in', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('redirect_uri', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('code_verifier', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('state', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });

    // Clear the session cookies set by node-oidc-provider
    res.clearCookie('_session', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
    res.clearCookie('.session.legacy', { httpOnly: true, secure: true });

    // Redirect to the end session endpoint
    const endSessionUrl = `${process.env.URL_AUTHORITY}/oidc/session/end?id_token_hint=${id_token}&post_logout_redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)}`;
    res.redirect(endSessionUrl);
});

//


